# How can I set the Account Record Type for Lead conversion?

Tags: apex, record-type, lead-conversion

I have a Lead that is automatically converted using a trigger. The default Record Type for this profile is Person Account and it works as expected. Now I need to explicitly set the Account Record Type for the conversion process as the profile should create different Record Types in the future.

First question:
How can I explicitly set the Account Record Type for Lead conversion in Apex?

Second question:
I have a unit test for the current behavior. I set the same profile for Lead creation and Lead conversion, but for some reason, I always end up with a Business Account. Any idea why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no way to set account record type during a lead conversion.  You will have to create the account first, before the lead conversion, and then use `setAccountId()` on the LeadConvert object to link the converted contact to the account.

Comment: Straightforward solution - Salesforce style. :D Thx!

Comment: Then lead field mapping configuration is useless.