# Lead conversion in unit test with wrong Account Record Type

Tags: apex, record-type, lead-conversion

I have an Inbound Email Handler that automatically creates a Lead and converts it. The Record Type for the corresponding Account is correctly set to the default Account Record Type that is configured in the used User Profile - in this case, it is created as a Person Account.

When I'm doing the same thing in a unit test it instead uses the Account Record Type, even though I'm using runAs() with a User that has the same User Profile set.

Why does this happen? Is there a way to test this?

A few months ago I already posted a very similar question: [How can I set the Account Record Type for Lead conversion?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/230167/how-can-i-set-the-account-record-type-for-lead-conversion)

Now the odd behavior that I experienced there became a real problem as it totally screws my tests and makes it impossible to know if I have introduced any regressions.

```
public with sharing class HandleEmailsHelper {
    public static void checkEmail(Messaging.InboundEmail email) {
        Lead ld = new Lead();
        ld.RecordTypeId = Utils.getRecordTypeId('Lead', 'Customer');
        insert ld;
    }
}

trigger LeadTrigger on Lead (before insert, before update, before delete, after insert, after update, after delete) {
    if (Trigger.isBefore && Trigger.isInsert) {
        LeadHelper.autoConvertCustomerLeads(Trigger.newMap);
    }
}

public with sharing class LeadHelper {
    public static void autoConvertCustomerLeads(Map<Id, Lead> leadMap) {
        List<Database.LeadConvert> leadCvtList = new List<Database.LeadConvert>();

        for (Lead ld : emailLeadMap.values()) {
            leadCvtList.add(setupLeadConvert(ld, null, convertStatus));
        }

        List<Database.LeadConvertResult> lcr = Database.convertLead(leadCvtList);
    }

    private static Database.LeadConvert setupLeadConvert(Lead ld, Id acctId, LeadStatus convertStatus) {
        Database.LeadConvert lc = new Database.LeadConvert();

        lc.setLeadId(ld.Id);
        lc.setOverwriteLeadSource(false);
        lc.setConvertedStatus(convertStatus.MasterLabel);

        if (acctId != null) {
            lc.setAccountId(acctId);
        }

        return lc;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you possibly share a minimal example of a unit test that causes this issue? I don't personally know the answer to this question but I think it's interesting and would love to experiment in a developer edition.

Comment: I will take it from production and strip out all the fluff and hope it will still behave the same way.

Comment: I added the code minus all the fluff - but it is still missing the actual test. I will add it later.